# Javascript. Is safe use async and await on front end?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I'm building a web application using angular.
I know that with ES6 i can use the async/wait, i found this guide how to use them transforming an Observable to Promise.
https://labs.encoded.io/2016/12/08/asyncawait-with-angular/
But it is safe? the browser is single thread, and i'm little bit afraid to use it thinking that it block all the UI.
Can someone give more information about it?
Thanks

Comment: `async` and `await` are just a syntax convenience around the Promise facility. It's essentially exactly like using Promises, and it's safe. A separate question that should be investigated is browser support for the syntax.

Comment: `async / await`, does not block the UI..

Comment: The exact purpose of async/await is to provide control flow with sync appearance but in non-blocking manner. As it was said, it's syntactic sugar for promises, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

It's not going to block the thread; at least not more than writing [callback-based code](https://nodejs.dev/learn/javascript-asynchronous-programming-and-callbacks). That's essentially it's whole point; It allows *writing asynchronous code as-if it was synchronous; making the flow far easier to reason about.*

It is more or less [syntactic sugar over on top of generators and promises](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#desugaring), which are non-blocking mechanisms for managing asynchronous actions.

That being said, they're not magic; the same mistakes that can make callback-based code block the thread can also block when written in `async`/`await`.

Comment: Generators are really unrelated to `async` functions.

Comment: @Pointy You are wrong - Babel for example transpiles an `async` function to a generator

Comment: Can you explain how they're related? A generator function returns objects synchronously.

Comment: @Pointy not in a comment - there's lots of material online

Comment: Oh I see - it's a technique that Babel uses, and I guess that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides This is relevant to the way how Babel implements it, not to native async/await. A similar thing was done with `co` and other coroutine libs before the arrival of async/await, but the statement that async/await *is* `co` is false.

Comment: @estus That's not what I stated. My statement is that generators and promises are mechanisms that can be used to manage asynchronous actions and `async/await` is sugar on top of them - Here's the spec: https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/

Comment: The answer is misleading and contains factual error. *async/await is more or less syntactic sugar over on top of generators and promises* - it's not. It's correct for Babel and TS with ES6 target. Not for Babel and TS with ES5 target. Not for native.

Comment: @estus Babel/TS use an emulated generator when transpiling `async/await` to ES5. That's because generators where not available at all in the JS engine at that point. `async/await` is implemented natively in browsers that already have generators, natively. I don't see why you would imply that browsers with native generators wouldn't build on top of that - the proposal even mentions that you do so. If you have evidence to the contrary - share it and I'll happily edit my answer

Comment: I didn't actually noticed it, sorry. I'm not totally sure if current implementations use actual `spawn` implementation that was suggested in *Informative Desugaring*. Any way, this link deserves to be mentioned in the answer for visibility, possibly with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Async/await is experimental and [part of ES7](http://rossboucher.com/await/#/). Server-side, NodeJS supports it (latest versions) but in a browser, it will almost certainly not be supported. Use good old Promises/Ajax instead.

> the browser is single thread, and i'm little bit afraid to use it
>   thinking that it block all the UI

Async/await / Promises / Ajax won't block the UI, by definition, because they are asynchronous.

Comment: question was not really about browser support if I'm not mistaken

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=await - IE11 and Opera Mini don't support it but otherwise it's available in browsers.

Comment: @Nicholas the title is "is it safe to use async/await on the front-end?" and the answer is clearly no.

Comment: `Async/await is experimental`, I think it's well past that stage now -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function  Also who doesn't transpile nowadays, most NPM modules are built this way now.  IOW: I would say it's very safe to use `async` / `await`.  `in a browser, it will almost certainly not be supported`, it's well suported, you can even play with it inside chrome console..

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah the body of the question hints whether it's safe in the context of blocking - Also - `async/await` is not experimental at all - IE being the only modern browser that doesn't support it. `async/await` is syntactic sugar on top of established ES6 features

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, i'm using Babel so i can use all ES6 features for all browsers ( adding some polyfills for IE11...), of course promise/ajax etc are asynchronous and they don't block the UI, but using await are you sure that it doesn't block the entire UI waiting the response from the server?

Comment: It doesn't - we are sure. Go ahead and use it if you are using Babel. This answer is not entirely correct - `async/await` is already supported by most major browsers without transpilation.

Comment: Yes, we are very very sure.. :)

Comment: Also, why don't you try it out? Put a delay in your server when sending a response and try to press some buttons in your UI while the request is in-flight